# Change for loop to forEach

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, foreach

I am working on a inventory updating program in vs2022 which I am using Gembox Spreadsheet for, It is working right now, but the boss man would like me to try to convert my for loop to a for each loop. The loop is what I am using to update my file.

Current For Loop

```
public void updateFile(string filename, int range, ItemLine selectedItem, decimal outValue)
    {
        var fullPath = $".\\Backend Files\\{filename}";
        SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE -LIMITED-KEY");
        var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(fullPath, new CsvLoadOptions(CsvType.CommaDelimited));
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        //foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows.Skip(1))
        //{
        //    foreach (var cell in row.AllocatedCells)
        //    {
        //        string updateValue = 
                
        //        if(cell.Value == int.TryParse((int)outValue, out int updateValue))
        //        {

        //        }
        //    }
        //}
        for (int i = 1; i <= range; i++)
        {
            var plan = worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
            var desc = worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
            var csvDescription = plan + " - " + desc;
            var platedescription = plan + " - ";
            if (selectedItem.ComboDescription == csvDescription)
            {
                worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = selectedItem.Quantity;
            }
            if (selectedItem.plateDescription == platedescription)
            {
                worksheet.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = selectedItem.Quantity;
            }
        }

        workbook.Save(fullPath, new CsvSaveOptions(CsvType.CommaDelimited));
    }
```

I beleive the forEach would look similar to this

```
 private static List<ItemLine> ReadFile(string fileName, string defaultValueDescription)
    {
        string path = $".\\Backend Files\\{fileName}";
        SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE -LIMITED-KEY");
        var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(path, new CsvLoadOptions(CsvType.CommaDelimited));
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        var items = new List<ItemLine>();
        items.Add(new ItemLine { Description = defaultValueDescription, Quantity = 0 });

        foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows.Skip(1))
        {
            var cells = row.AllocatedCells;

            var il = new ItemLine();
            if (cells.Count == 2)
            {
                il.Description = cells[0].Value?.ToString() ?? "Description Not Found";
                il.Quantity = cells[1].IntValue;
            }
            else if (cells.Count >= 3)
            {
                il.Plan = cells[0].Value?.ToString() ?? "Plan Not Found";
                il.Description = cells[1].Value?.ToString() ?? "Description Not Found";
                il.Quantity = cells[2].IntValue;
            }

            items.Add(il);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Those two pieces of code look almost *entirely* different to me. Even the method names are significantly different. You'll need to make the question *much* clearer if we're going to be able to help you.

Comment: I would question your boss about why he wants you to refactor working code to use a different type of loop.